# Где найти материал по MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Подскажите, где найти материал по теме "загрузка данных в MySQL с поднятыми (включенными) ограничениями (constraints)." Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В документации на офф. сайте: [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Истина, отмечай как правильный ответ. )